# Are there any advantages of using TextUtil class over String class in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, textutils

I was reading the Android documentation and saw some familiar methods in TextUtils which i normally use in String class, and I also discovered that the method `String.split(String regex)` was removed, but is present in TexUtils class. So i started to wonder why thy even bothered adding duplicate methods in TextUtils which were originally present in String class

Answer (score 0):

I often use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` to check whether string is empty or not (string!=null && string.length>0)